# Rails/Mongoid relationship question with Struct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, mongoid5

I have this library app I'm building and it has 3 classes. State, Library, and Book. The State has many libraries and Library belongs_to a State. The Library has many Books, and book is embedded in a library. However, when I make this auto_pick_job and we get to the `top_free_book` and call `library.state`. library.state is nil for some reason. I would expect to get the state back but no dice.. The way I'm calling and creating Libraries are as follows. So Library will always belong_to an existing State.

```
state = Stats.find(x)
library = state.libaries.new(info)
library.save_optimistic!
```

I'm would also be grateful for relationship help using Struct.

```
class State
  has_many: libraries
end

class Library
  belongs_to :state
end

class Book
  embedded_in :library

  def self.top_free_book(library_id)
    library = Library.find(library_id)    
    library.state
  end

  AutoPickJob = Struct.new(:library_id) do
    def perform     
      Book.top_free_book(library_id)
    end
  end

  def queue_auto_pick
    auto_pick_job = AutoPickJob.new(library_id)
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(auto_pick_job)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`belongs_to` usually validates presence of the relationship, but if you already have some models that were created prior to `belongs_to` association being added, they won't necessarily have the association target set on them.

Separately, it is possible to destroy `State` documents even when there are referencing libraries (the default behavior for associations is nullify). If you delete rather than destroy `State` documents, this doesn't run callbacks and can leave libraries referencing deleted states.

So, ensure that all of your libraries do:

1. Have `state_id` set.
2. Have these `state_id`s reference existing state documents.

Comment: Where are you suggesting I have `state_id` set? I know the State exists because when I try State.find('state_id') from the console it returns. Even when I call `@library.state` it returns in console. It simply doesn't return when I make a http request.

Comment: I've updated my question to contain how I'm creating Libraries. It's always associated with an state so I don't know why it's mismatching.

Comment: `state_id` should be filled out by Mongoid if models are created via associations. Verify that it is set by looking at the attributes of a library (`Library.find(id)`, `Library.find(id).state_id`).